# Mac won't boot with new RAM installed

Tags: mac-mini

I have a Mac mini (Macmini3,1). I was origionally told that, at most, it can only take 4 GB of RAM. When I bought the Mac it had 2 GB so I went to Fry's and got 2x 2 GB sticks.

Here is the info on the memory. Both are the same; I can't remember the manufacturer's name.

```
Size:   2 GB
Type:   DDR3
Speed:  1067 MHz
Manufacturer:   0x8502
Part Number:    0x505344333247313036363253000000000000
Serial Number:  0x00000000
```

Today, I got Mactracker from the App Store. It has data on all the Macs that ever existed.

It says that the Macmini3,1 has a maximum capacity for 8 GB of RAM but Apple only supports using up to 4 GB. Before I go out and get the RAM, I'm wondering if any of you have tried putting 8 GB of RAM on a Macmini3,1.

Today I bought [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231294&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-_-RSSDailyDeals-_-na-_-na&AID=10521304&PID=4169666&SID=7loorpplnkaq) RAM.

I installed the RAM as someone suggested but the Mac wouldn't even boot; what I mean is the power supply wouldn't even turn on. I just saw the white light in the front and that's it. I left it on for 5 minutes and still nothing. I took it apart checked all wires a few times and tried a few times and still wouldn't turn on. I eventually gave up and put the old RAM back in and it worked.

Is it possible that the RAM is bad and I should have it replaced? Or I should use another brand?

Comment: Please include *all* relevant information in the body of your question.  If there is a lot of information, summarize the salient points.  Links to external sites are discouraged because those resources could disappear at some point.  (Stack Exchange sites aim to provide a lasting resource that will not just be helpful to the person posting the question, but others searching on that topic in the future.)

Comment: But to provide a brief answer to your question, yes, the RAM is probably faulty and should be replaced.  Newegg has a good return policy, so you should have no trouble.

Comment: First, make sure the RAM is pushed in all the way. If it still doesn't work, get some new RAM (check to make sure it's compatible).

Comment: yea i checked a few times it was all the way in. can you suggest another brand i can try that has been tried?

Comment: Worth noting that that Mac Mini could only support 8GB ram with a specific firmware update (though I'm struggling to find exact details on it, but its mentioned here: http://www.macminicolo.net/state2009.html). I assume if you've been using it regularly since purchase you'd have all updates installed though?

Answer (score 4):

I can only suggest that you have a faulty ram. Try installing just one stick of ram to see if it boots. 
Have a look at this document. Hope it helps
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4432

Comment: I'll second this suggestion. Until ram fails 3 times - reseating each time more carefully than the last, it could be user error. You can easily mix things to determine which of the two sticks might be bad.